# HTML drop down menu links are not working?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm a beginner web design student. I created two drop-down menus for my website: projects and labs, and though the drop-down menu itself is working and the links are clickable, they don't direct you to the relative links I provided. It just stays on the same page. I'm entirely unsure what about my HTML is wrong in that aspect. My page is as follows: http://krystwal.infinityfreeapp.com/artdm171/index.html

```html
<nav class="dropdown">
  <section class="projects">
    <button><h4>Projects</h4></button>
    <ul class="projectlist">

      <li><a href="projects/project2/index.html"><strong>2: Wireframes &amp; Style Tiles</strong> 10 April 2021</a></li>

      <li><a href="projects/project2/index.html"><strong>3: Multi-page Website</strong> 21 May 2021</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section class="labs">
    <button><h4>Labs</h4></button>

    <ul class=lablist>
      <li><a href="../index.html.html"><strong>1: Domain Landing Page</strong> 08 March 2021</a></li>
      <li><a href="labs/lab2/index.html"><strong>2: Mt. Washington HTML</strong> 15 March 2021</a></li>
      <li><a href="labs/lab3/index.html"><strong>3: Mt. Washington CSS</strong> 12 April 2021</a></li>
      <li><a href="labs/lab4/index.html"><strong>4: Mt. Washington Table</strong> 17 April 2021</a></li>
      <li><a href="labs/lab5/index.html"><strong>5: Responsive Design</strong> 01 May 2021</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS:

```html
.projectlist {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.lablist {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.dropdown {
    height: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.projects, .labs {
    position: relative;
}

.projects ul, .labs ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(252, 166, 126, 1);
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.projects ul {
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
}

.projects a, .labs a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.projects li, .labs li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.projects a:hover, .labs a:hover {
    color:white;
}

.dropdown button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown button:hover {
    color:orangered;
}

.projects button:focus + ul,
.labs button:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically the links work fine. The issue is actually being caused because of your `pointer-events: none` style on the default state of the list of links.

As soon as you click, the focus on your button is lost which means that the overwritten value provided in the following rule is lost:

```css
.projects button:focus + ul, .labs button:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all; // This is no longer the case when the focus is lost
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

And so although the menu is visible, clicking on a menu item will be impossible.

You may want to have a think about changing the approach to toggle the `display` property on the list element between `none` and `block` (or something similar).

An approach like that will cause layout shift, and consequently affect your [Cumulative Layout Shift score for Core Web Vitals](https://web.dev/cls/).

Alternatively you could achieve a similar dropdown effect by making the list element positioned absolutely inside of a containing relatively positioned parent. This will avoid layout shift, and allow you to still hide the list (via the display property) from all users (including accessibilty users because an element with a `none` display isn't focussable and is skipped on the accessibility tree).